# Using gcloud SDK to download metrics for Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-dataflow

How can I use the command-line interface for GCP and download metrics such as utilization, autoscaling and backlogs via `gcloud`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no available `gcloud` command yet to retrieve Cloud Monitoring metrics through command-line interface.

On the other hand, you may use the `cURL` command approach for this.

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) "https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/<projectID>/timeSeries?interval.startTime=2022-01-31T13:45:46-05:00&interval.endTime=2022-02-02T14:05:06-05:00&filter="metric.type=\"dataflow.googleapis.com/job/total_vcpu_time\"%20AND%20resource.labels.job_name=\"<job-name>\"""
```

You may use your desired [Time Series](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2FPROJECT_ID%22%2C%22aggregation.alignmentPeriod%22%3A%22600s%22%2C%22aggregation.perSeriesAligner%22%3A%22ALIGN_MEAN%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22metric.type%3D%5C%22compute.googleapis.com%2Finstance%2Fcpu%2Futilization%5C%22%22%2C%22interval.endTime%22%3A%222021-09-01T10%3A00%3A00-04%3A00%22%2C%22interval.startTime%22%3A%222021-09-01T09%3A40%3A00-04%3A00%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22timeSeries.metric%2CtimeSeries.points%22%7D) followed by your desired [Metric Type](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-dataflow). You may also add additional parameters like the JobName/instance (just like my sample script) depending on your desired output by using the documetnation I provided as reference.